# TFLite YOLO8 model validation ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 640 but expected 480 for dimension 1 of input 0

Tags: validation, dimensions, tflite, yolov8

I'm trying to validate my YOLOv8 "detector.tflite" by :yolo detect val model=detector.tflite data=data.yaml
but I'm getting dimensions error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/bin/yolo", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(entrypoint())
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/cfg/__init__.py", line 391, in entrypoint
    getattr(model, mode)(**overrides)  # default args from model
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/model.py", line 301, in val
    validator(model=self.model)
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/yolo/engine/validator.py", line 158, in __call__
    preds = model(batch['img'])
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ultralytics/nn/autobackend.py", line 377, in forward
    self.interpreter.set_tensor(input['index'], im)
  File "/home/matanc/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py", line 696, in set_tensor
    self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch. Got 480 but expected 640 for dimension 2 of input 0.
```

I was trying to adapt 'imgsz' but it's not the issue. Also I don't have the .pt file.
Is there a way to run validation using the ultralytics command?
Thanks.